# Does gold have elastic behavior?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, solid-mechanics, elasticity

I know structural steel is considered to have an elastic behavior and after a certain deformation, it has a plastic behavior.

How about gold metal?

Comment: When I search about `gold elasticity`, the returned results are about business science and supply/demand.

Comment: Gold has similar behaviour, try searching "[gold mechanical properties](https://www.google.com/search?q=gold+mechanical+properties&oq=gold+mechanical+properties)" for more.

Comment: Technically, all materials have some degree of elasticity. That is a different matter from whether a material makes a viable spring, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gold has a Young's modulus of 79 GPa which is very similar to silver, but significantly lower than iron or steel.

[https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=ktn&LN=NO&NM=230#:~:text=The%20Young%27s%20modulus%20of%20elasticity,lower%20than%20iron%20or%20steel](https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=ktn&LN=NO&NM=230#:%7E:text=The%20Young%27s%20modulus%20of%20elasticity,lower%20than%20iron%20or%20steel).

Comment: Right. Steel has a Young's modulus of 200 GB. Almost `2.5` times that of gold.

Comment: Interestingly, steel density is almost `2.5` times less than gold.